# Summernote with bootstrap 5 font styling and font sizing doesn't work

Tags: bootstrap-5, summernote

I'm integrating summernote-bs5 in my software. I include it from cdn:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.20/summernote-bs5.min.css" integrity="sha512-ngQ4IGzHQ3s/Hh8kMyG4FC74wzitukRMIcTOoKT3EyzFZCILOPF0twiXOQn75eDINUfKBYmzYn2AA8DkAk8veQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.20/summernote-bs5.min.js" integrity="sha512-6F1RVfnxCprKJmfulcxxym1Dar5FsT/V2jiEUvABiaEiFWoQ8yHvqRM/Slf0qJKiwin6IDQucjXuolCfCKnaJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

I initialize summernote area using default. Html:

```html
<div class="mt-2">
    <label class="control-label" for="textarea">Descrizione breve:</label>
    <textarea class="summernote" name="content_abstract"><?=$content->content_abstract?>. 
    </textarea>
</div>
```

js:

```js
$('.summernote').summernote();
```

It doesn't work. I tried also with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uczqdbka/1/) with bootstrap last version and it seems not work. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uczqdbka/1/)

Answer (score 5):

if you are using summernote and the dropdowns are not oppening in bs5, try this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.summernote').summernote();
        var noteBar = $('.note-toolbar');
        noteBar.find('[data-toggle]').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('data-bs-toggle', $(this).attr('data-toggle')).removeAttr('data-toggle');
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have this error : Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this as a basic test and it worked for me. Are you adding everything in the correct order and are you waiting for the document to be loaded to initialise your summernote div?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.summernote').summernote();
    });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- include summernote css/js -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="mt-2">
        <label class="control-label" for="textarea">Descrizione breve:</label>
        <textarea class="summernote" name="content_abstract"><?=$content->content_abstract?>.</textarea>
    </div>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: This does not load with bootstrap 5 theme

Answer (score 0):

this work for me (Asp net core 6) 
I have tried to use summernote beside the  Bootstrap v5.1.0 and seem not to work.
then I tried to use the without bootstrap version of summernote and work fine
**note 1**
as the official website of summernote says:

> Requires HTML5 doctype
> Bootstrap uses certain HTML elements and CSS properties which require HTML5 doctype. Include  in the beginning of all your projects.

**note 2** while I am using _layout which contains the initialisation of the html document, I put all of the links below in the head

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>
```

and i put this script in the end of the body element :

```
<script>
  $('#summernote').summernote({
    placeholder: 'Hello stand alone ui',
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 120,
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['style']],
      ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
      ['table', ['table']],
      ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
      ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
    ]
  });
</script>
```

finally you can put

```
 <div id="summernote"></div>
```

where ever you want while you are using the _layout that has the previous links and script

**note 3** you can still using bootstarp in your layout and it will not affect